# TYPO3 Show fe_user with Hyperlink and GET parameter

Tags: hyperlink, get, request, typo3, typoscript

I'm using `TYPO3 7.6` and I'd like to send an email with a Hyperlink to my TYPO3-Website (page=123). On this page I've listed all `fe_users` with the following `TypoScript`, but I'll only show one specific user, f.e. `uid=20`.

I have two questions:

1. How can I show only this user (uid) on my page?
2. How do I call my hyperlink?

Show all users:

```
lib.feUserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
    table = fe_users

    select.pidInList = 10
    select.max = 10
    select.orderBy = last_name DESC
    where = disable = 0

    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = first_name
        10.wrap = wq<p><strong>|&nbsp;
        ...         
        14 = TEXT
        14.field = email
        14.wrap = |</p>
    }
}
```

-> 1. Then I have to edit my `WHERE`clause, but i dont't know how? All of my tests won't work.

```
lib.feUserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
  table = fe_users
  ...
  andWhere.dataWrap = uid={GP:fe_users|uid}
  #andWhere.data = GP:feuseruid
  #andWhere.data = GP:fe_user|uid
  #andWhere.intval = 1
  #andWhere.wrap = uid=|
 ...
```

-> 2. And how can I show only the User from the GET-Parameter?

```
http://my.domain.tld/index.php?id=123&uid=20
http://my.domain.tld/index.php?id=123&feuser=20
http://my.domain.tld/index.php?id=123&fe_users[uid]=20
...
```

I hope someone can give me a crucial tip ... 
... thank you.

Regards
Stefan

---

my solution was

```
lib.feuserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
    table = fe_users

    select {
        pidInList = 10
        orderBy = last_name DESC
        where = uid = ###field_uid###
        markers.field_uid.data = GP:user
        markers.field_uid.intval = 1
        max = 1
    }
    ...
```

Thanks for helping ...

Comment: For 1st you can use [markers](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html#markers) and for 2nd you can set parameters accordingly from 1st one.

Comment: Is it like .. `where = uid = ###whatever### ` and  `markers { whatever.data = GP:uid    }`? And the link `?id=123&user=456&`

Comment: ups .. `index.php?id=123&uid=456`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Build link to page 123 with uid parameter from fe_user. Adds something like

*?id=123&user=456&cHash=789*

```
lib.feUserLink = CONTENT
lib.feUserLink {
    table = fe_users
    select {
        pidInList = 10
        max = 10
        orderBy = last_name DESC
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = username
        10.typolink {
            parameter = 123
            additionalParams.dataWrap = &user={field:uid}
            useCacheHash = 1
        }
        10.wrap = |</br>
    }
}
```

1) To show only selected user in given list, adapt your select like

```
[globalVar = GP:user > 0]
lib.feUserLink.select {
    where = uid = ###field_uid###
    markers.field_uid.data = GP:user
    markers.field_uid.intval = 1
    max = 1
}
[global]
```

You don't need clause *where = disable = 0*. Its already included in the SQL query by default.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help and post .. i'll try it. I tried a lot of versions, maybe I forgot the cHash. I don't want to use cHash, so  I will use `useCashHash=0`

Comment: If you dont use cHash, most of requests will not load expected content if you not set hole page to be non cachable. I f you use real url, you can make nice human readable url without having cHash appended

Comment: thanks jokumer for your help. I disable the cache (page properties no_cache=1) for this special page. Everything works fine.